# Get N characters from string, respecting full words python

Tags: python

I am using this code to get the first 4000 characters of a long text.

```
text = data[0:4000]
print(text)
```

data is the variable containing the long text, now the problem is when I print text, at the end, I get half a word, for example "con" while the word should be "content".

I am wondering if there is a way to ensure the words aren't truncated.

Comment: Are you saying you want at least 4000 characters, but more if final word requires more?

Comment: yes i want 4000 characters + the number of characters necessary to end the last word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the first space after 4000 characters.  You can use `max` to account for text that ends a few characters past 4000, but with no space at the end.

```
ix = max(data.find(' ', 4000), 4000)
text = data[:ix]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's no trailing space and you're midway through the final word.

Comment: thought for a while that the code isn't working, due to other errors but it's working perfectly now thank you

Answer (score 2):

A simple find statement that looks for a space beginning at character 4000 gets this started

```
x = txt.find(' ',4000)
```

But to avoid truncating the last word then you need to test the results of your find statement.

If the starting point of 4000 is within the last word then it will return a -1 and you'll print/return the entire text.

If the starting point is before the last word then it will return the index of the next space and you'll print up to that index

```
x = txt.find(' ',4000)
if x < 0:
    print (txt)
else:
    print (txt[:x])
```

Also remember that the starting point on find is zero based so if the 4000th character is a space it will find the next space. As a simple example, the following code will return "four five" rather than simply "four". If this is not the desired result then consider using 3999 in your find.

```
txt = "four five six"
x = txt.find(' ',5)
print(txt[:x])
# returns "four five"
```